# How can I draw over a panel in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

Hey, I need to do my drawing over a panel in C# but without placing my drawing code inside "panel1_Paint", how can I do that ??
BTW, I'm using WinForms.

**Update** : I forgot to make something clear, I need not to place my drawing code inside paint handler, because I need to start drawing depending on buttons' events.

Comment: Why do you want to place it somewhere else and not in the paint event handler?

Comment: Do you want to place the code in a separate method to be called from the Paint event? The only other option is to create a class that derives from Panel and draw in the OnPaint method.

Comment: How can I connect the panel component with the derived class you talked about?? more explanation please?

Comment: Please explain why you cannot use the paint event. That may help clear up some of the confusion.

Comment: @'I need not to place my drawing code inside paint handler, because I need to start drawing depending on buttons' events': A much more proper design would be to store that this event happened and redraw the control in its paint event, or using a buffer (see my answer). Just drawing into the graphics of the panel is not a very elegant solution, as everything that was painted will be lost on the next redraw event (try minimizing the window and bring it up again).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually you do all your drawings in the paint event handler. If you want to do any update (if a user clicks on the panel for example) you have to defer that action: you store the required data (coordinates where the user clicked) and force a redraw of the control. This causes the paint event to be fired, where you can then draw things you stored before.

Another way would be (if you really want to draw outside of the 'panel1_Paint' event handler) to draw inside a buffer image, and copy the image to the controls graphics object in the paint event handler.

**Update:**

An example:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Bitmap buffer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Initialize buffer
        panel1_Resize(this, null);
    }

    private void panel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Resize the buffer, if it is growing
        if (buffer == null || 
            buffer.Width < panel1.Width || 
            buffer.Height < panel1.Height)
        {
            Bitmap newBuffer = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
            if (buffer != null)
                using (Graphics bufferGrph = Graphics.FromImage(newBuffer))
                    bufferGrph.DrawImageUnscaled(buffer, Point.Empty);
            buffer = newBuffer;
        }
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Draw the buffer into the panel
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(buffer, Point.Empty);
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Draw into the buffer when button is clicked
        PaintBlueRectangle();
    }

    private void PaintBlueRectangle()
    {
        // Draw blue rectangle into the buffer
        using (Graphics bufferGrph = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
        {
            bufferGrph.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue, 1), 1, 1, 100, 100);
        }

        // Invalidate the panel. This will lead to a call of 'panel1_Paint'
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Now the drawn images wont be lost, even after a redraw of the control, because it only draws out the buffer (the image, saved in the memory). Additionally you can draw things anytime a event occurs, by simply drawing into the buffer.

Comment: Upvoted, but I'd really like it if the Refresh() was changed to panel1.Invalidate(), and if the rendering was done in its own function, called by the button's click event. Attaching a resize handler to resize the buffer would be the icing. :)

Comment: Thanks that's what I was thinking about, but couldn't figure it all alone.

Comment: Can I use this technique to connect two panels with two different buffers?

Comment: what do you mean with 'connect two panels'? do you want to write into the buffer of the other one? you could post a new question specifying the goal you want to archieve.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: what happens when you come back to your application, after using another application that covers up part or all of your window?

What you should be doing is rendering what you need to an offscreen bitmap, called a buffer. You'll render the image whenever you want, in response to anything that changes what the image should display. Then, from the panel's paint event, you'll copy from that buffer to the panel.

Graphics programming is a lot of fun. It might seem like there are a lot of details to consider, but there aren't many once you learn them. But this is an area where a slapdash approach will show through, and can make an application feel very unreliable and unprofessional.

Comment: @overslacked/phild: For a novice, this explanation might be difficult to understand. Maybe one of you could post a code sample? It would be good to have a less hackish way than mine shown.

Comment: @Charles M - honestly, my point is more about patience and consideration, rather than sticking in the first bit of code that seems to accomplish the task. I have other answers (as many do), easily searchable, that quite well describe the methods needed.